# 3 textboxes , 3 column in 1 data query

Tags: mysql, excel, string, vb.net, system

Hi guys once again i am in need of your help ive encountered another problem that which involves mysql

In the string variables code line it just make the "saved data" in the mysql database in one column like one straight column example in vbform is cmbboxbreed1 = golden retriever
Cmbboxbreed2= german sheperd

But in mysql its just one column

Breed
Golden retriever German Shepard

the thing that i aim for is they're in different columns
Mysql-

Id  Breed
1   Golden retriever
2   German Shepherd

````
Dim person as new ownerclass
Dim doggo as new dogclass
Dim breed as new breedclass

Dim fname as string = txtboxfname.text
Dim lname as string = txtboxlname.text

Dim brd as string = comboboxbrd1.text &""& cmbboxbrd2.txt &"" & cmmbboxbrd3.txt&" "&

Dim name as string 
=txtboxname1.text &""& txtboxname2.txt &"" & txtboxname3.txt&" "&

Dim age as string =txtboxage1.text &""& txtboxage2.txt &"" & txtboxage3.txt&" "&


If verif and person.insertowner(fname,lname) then
Msgbox("yes")
Else
Msgbox ("sorry")
End if
End sub

Function verif as boolean
If txtboxfname.text.trim = " " or (allofthe txtboxes and comboboxes ).text.trim =" "
Else 
Return true
End if
End function

`
CLASSES
`
public function insertowner(byval fname as string ,byval lname as string) as boolean

Using command as new mysqlcommand(" insert into table(fname,lname) values (@fn,@ln),db.Connection" 

Command.parameter.add("@fn",mysqldbtype.varchar).value = fname

Db.connection

If command.executenonquery =  1 then
Return true
Else 
Return false
End if
End using```


In the dim brd as string line code ... Though it does work but its just one column not separated pls help
Current code excution
Breed
Golden Retriever German Shepherd
I aim for
Id   Breed
1.    Golden Retriever
2.    German Shepherd
````

Comment: Each breed/combo box should have a separate variable and be inserted into MySQL separately then

Comment: Eg insertBreed1, insertBreed2

Comment: It worked but now say i adopted 2 instead of 3 ... The 3rd textbox would still register in mysql but blank

Comment: You'd have to do 3 boxes since you have three points you want to store. If a dog doesnt have three breeds it would just stay empty, right?